# matlab - Optimization with inverse and pseudoinverse

Tags: optimization, inverse, matlab, pseudoinverse

Let us assume I have to optimize this system:

$$\min_{x\in S} \left|\left|\left(E\begin{bmatrix}
    I_n\\
    A'(x)^{-1}C'(x)\\
\end{bmatrix}\right)^+ a -b\right|\right|^{2}$$

Where x is the vector of my unknowns, A', B' are matrices depending on x while a and b are constant vectors with correct dimensions and E is a matrix with correct dimensions too.
S are the constaints on my x variables which are simple linear inequalities.

Which is the best approach in order to solve this problem? Suggestions?
How to handle both pseudo inverse and inverse?

Comment: @snulty ok, done

Comment: I was just suggesting it because it might tidy up some algebra, and at the end you can probably sub back in for the A' and C'

Comment: @snulty yes, this is a good idea. Thank you but still i can't figure out how to handle this problem in matlab

Comment: My only guess would be to try expanding out as something like this $ \left(a^\dagger E\begin{bmatrix}
    I_n \\
    A'(x)^{-1}C'(x)\\
\end{bmatrix}  -b^\dagger\right)\left(\begin{bmatrix}
    I_n &
    (A'(x)^{-1}C'(x))^\dagger\\
\end{bmatrix}E^\dagger a -b\right)$ assuming $a$ and $b$ are column vectors, and then trying to differentiate and set it equal to zero to solve for a critical point/minimum. Maybe you can do a type of root finding on that equation with the parameters in $x$? Or maybe someone else has some better suggestions

Comment: The $(\cdot)^+$ function is convex but not linear, and the norm is not nondecreasing, so the objective is not convex. This is a hard problem.